# Small edger engine - hard to start

Tags: starting, small-engine, two-stroke

I have a small edger 2-stroke that is hard to start. I cleaned plug, washed sponge air filter and it still won’t start. I sprayed starter fluid in air intake and it started. While running I put air filter back in. Engine ran great the whole time.
This seems to rule out a problem gas filter , or plug. What can I check to fix this.

Comment: Have you checked the priming bulb/tubes for any leaks?

Comment: Ethanol attracts water in gasoline. This may eventually result in residue clogging the diaphragm carburetor's passages. Are you familiar with 2-stroke carburetor disassembly, cleaning and repair?

Comment: I did not observe any leaks and once started, it ran fine. Is this behavior consistent with a Carb issue? I figured if the Carb was clogged, it would not run at all or very poorly.